# Sistema de Digital Signage com NodeJS, é possível?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webkit

Tenho uma dúvida sobre `Node JS` e o que eu poderia fazer com ele. Eu comecei a estudar sobre `MEAN` já faz alguns dias e queria saber se utilizando dessa tecnologia eu conseguiria, por exemplo, criar um sistema de `Digital Signage`, como o `Xibo` ou `Onsee`.

Uma breve explicação sobre como funciona esses sistemas, pra facilitar o entendimento de vocês... Esses sistemas têm uma administração que roda via web e um cliente que roda no sistema operacional. Nessa administração é onde as companhias cadastram as campanhas(vídeos, imagens, etc) e define os horários de exibição das campanhas. Essas campanhas são exibidas no cliente em um loop.

Sei que separadamente é possível sim fazer os dois, a administração usando `MEAN` e o software pro PC utilizando `Node WebKit`, mas a dúvida é exatamente essa, se eu consigo juntar os dois e fazer um sistema desses.

Comment: Sim, consegue. Você faz o client acessar o servidor de tempos em tempos, ou mantém uma conexão aberta via websocket, e deixa o servidor avisar quando o conteúdo muda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Com certeza, consegue sim.

Dê uma olhada nestes [aplicativos de exemplo](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/List-of-apps-and-companies-using-node-webkit) para se inspirar.

Você pode fazer a comunicação usando REST, Websockets, ZeroMQ, Torrent, etc.
O desenho dessa arquitetura vai depender mais das regras do seu negócio, por exemplo a natureza do conteúdo, se precisa ser real-time, a frequência em que novo conteúdo é produzido, se a distribuição é igual para todos os terminais ou se haverá filtros, e assim por diante.

Em geral, eu tentaria manter o software dos terminais o mais enxuto possível, para que fique leve e de fácil manutenção. Você pode pensar também em um mecanismo de auto-atualização, para distribuir correções de bugs e versões novas do software automaticamente.

Dependendo do que você precisa, talvez possa usar apenas um browser.
Com [HTML5](http://html5demos.com/) você pode fazer um app que funcione [offline](http://sergiolopes.org/palestra-appcache-html5-offline/), em tela cheia, com banco de dados local, etc e manter seu software atualizado o tempo todo.

Se quiser ir [por esse caminho](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/offline), veja o seguinte:

- [application cache](http://html5demos.com/offlineapp)
- [localStorage](http://html5demos.com/storage)
- [web SQL & indexed database](http://html5demos.com/database)
- [online/offline events](http://html5demos.com/offline)

Se quiser uma sugestão mais específica, fique a vontade para perguntar. Abraços, sucesso no seu projeto.